# Make arrays from unique prime number?

Tags: primes

I came across a passage in the book "Quantum Computing since Democritus" by Scott Aaronson.
So it goes,

*When I was in junior high school, I had a friend who was really good at math, but maybe not so good at programming. He wanted to write a program using arrays, but he didn’t know what an array was. So what did he do? He associated each element of the array with a unique prime number, then he multiplied them all together; then, whenever he wanted to read something out of the array, he factored the product.*

The author does not go into any more detail of this. My question is how exactly does that work?

p.s. I'm not entirely sure if this should be in Math stack exchange or here.

Comment: Knowing how it works would require knowing what he's talking about. I can't figure out what he's talking about. To me, that makes this more of a riddle than a programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about the specifics of this, but I think this has something to do with the [Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic)

If you've never heard of it, it states that *each number is a product of a unique combination of primes.*

Now back to the question. Lets assume that you have an array that looks like this:

`[ 5, 6, 1, 4, 7 ]`

Each index would be assigned a prime number, sort of like a Hash Table.

So: 5 would map to a prime, lets say 2, then 6 would map to another prime, lets say 3, etc. Then what would happen is that those prime numbers, when multiplied, would form a number that is ONLY created from those primes. This is the number that then encodes the indices. So when you "factor the product" it returns the same values that you initially multiplied with no variance.

I should mention, this is not something that is practical or wise to implement, since its just silly. But I hope this helps you to understand the problem a bit better

**EDIT:** Yes this probably does belong on the Math Stackexchange

Comment: Basically an array is still in used, but the author's friend just complicated things by using prime number indices? So I thought he is talking about something else that substitutes arrays all along...

Comment: So, suppose I want to read the 4th element out, and all I have is the product of primes. Then I factor the product into the unique primes. Now what do I do?

Comment: @JamesReinstateMonicaPolk the index would be the 4th smallest prime. I'm not saying this is an efficient algorithm, its just a silly idea that some maths nerd came up with. Its a bit like the Bogosort: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogosort